# Upgrading a rails 3.0 app to 3.2 including Compass and Blueprint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, blueprint, compass-sass

Tearing my hair out with this.

Trying to upgrade an old app to rails 3.2

Have got most of the way there but I keep hitting an error when the app tries to import blueprint.

```
    Started GET "/assets/application.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-15 15:46:53 +0100
    Error compiling asset application.css:
    Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: blueprint.
```

and the same for every other compass or blueprint imported item.

I've followed the instructions at http://compass-blueprint.org/install/
I've tried adding 
        *= require blueprint
into my application.css
I've tried putting files in various places, but nothign seems to be work.

There seem to be lots of advice for setting up a new install but not for migrating one, so I'm not sure what files are supposed to be where or where to find them in the first place.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the Rails Guides explaination on the Asset Pipeline here; http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Upgrading can be a pain, so be sure to read up on [Asset Organization](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization) and pay close attention to the old files in the public/ directory.

Comment: I've really tried, but there don't appear to be any blueprint files in the public directory. And I'm loath to go fishing around in the framework files under /vendor/bundle/... where they appear to be.

Comment: You'll most likely have to move the files from /vender/* into assets/* in order to use the asset pipeline properly. Try the blueprintcss-rails gem here; github.com/bai/blueprint-rails

Comment: Managed to get it done somehow with an awful lot of pain and blind alleys... Mostly just hacking away and moving things and fixing bugs one by one...